# How to add new field to elasticsearch exist mapping and set values?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

How to add new field to exist elastic search mapping.I want to set that field to default value.How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution using kibana query you can use it. There is a two steps. first one adds new field. second one is to update field value. You can use an index prefix also.

```
    # First step >> add new field to mapping
    PUT <index_name or prefix>/_mapping/<Document-type>
    {
    "properties": {
    "source": {
    "type": "<field type>"
             }
        }
    }

    # Second step is add default values to field
    POST /<index name or prefix>/_update_by_query
    {
     "script": {
         "source": "ctx._source.source = 'Hi... .'",
           "lang": "painless"
         },
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}
        }
     }
```

Comment: It will work but how many documents do you have? Make an update by query matchall on millions of documents could be dangerous.

Comment: mmm. i have something like  100000 or 200000 document count. but it's working so we can filter document count using search query.Anyway need to think about what can be happened  with millions documents.  :) thanks

Comment: If you updating all documents, it s better to reindex (update will almost delete - add), reindex will be better.

Comment: ye s i'm suing it for update all documents

Comment: Well according to Es (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-1-3-calculating-updating-a-field-in-millions-of-documents/36114) reindex all document is the best practice.

POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter",
    "version_type": "external"
  },
  "script": {
   "source": "ctx._source.source = 'Hi... .'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}